# Spring/Hibernate @Transactional on method prevents update SQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

- Spring v4.2.5 Release
- Hibernate v5.1.0.Final

I have a Junit test method which performs a load, updates a property and calls `saveOrUpdate(bean)`.

It's behaving oddly in that adding `@Transactional` to the method signature prevents the update SQL from being performed (No SQL generated in log).

Remove the `@Transactional` and the update SQL is generated and the database updated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(
        {
            "classpath:jdbc.properties",
            "classpath:hibernate.properties"
        })
@ComponentScan(value = "com.savant.test.spring.donorservice.core.dao")
public class ApplicationContext {


    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        // Hikari is a connection pool manager.
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setIsolateInternalQueries(true);
        System.out.println(dataSource);

        dataSource.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT count(*) from system.onerow");
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(3);
        dataSource.setAutoCommit(false);

        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource datasouce) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(datasouce);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(package_to_scan);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }


    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put(hibernate_dialect, env.getProperty(hibernate_dialect));
        hibernateProperties.put(hibernate_current_session_context_class, env.getProperty(hibernate_current_session_context_class));
        hibernateProperties.put(hibernate_connection_autocommit, env.getProperty(hibernate_connection_autocommit));
        hibernateProperties.put(hibernate_format_sql, env.getProperty(hibernate_format_sql));
        hibernateProperties.put(hibernate_hbm2ddl_auto, env.getProperty(hibernate_hbm2ddl_auto));
        hibernateProperties.put(hibernate_show_sql, env.getProperty(hibernate_show_sql));
//        hibernateProperties.put(hibernate_connection_provider_class, env.getProperty(hibernate_connection_provider_class));
        return hibernateProperties;

    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
```

The entities have been auto-generated using Netbeans 'Entity classes from Database'.

The main Entity has 
A one-to-one relationship with FetchType.EAGER 
A one-to-many relationship with FetchType.EAGER (it was LAZY - read below).

The test method looks like this.

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void c_testUpdateAddress1() {
        System.out.println("findById");
        String id = donorId;
        Donor donor = donorDao.findById(id);

        donor.setAbogrp(" O");

        for (DonorAddress da : donor.getDonorAddressCollection()) {
            da.setAddr1("Updated line");
            System.out.println(da.getDonorAddressPK().getAddrtype() + " " + da.getAddr1());
        }

        System.out.println("Update");

        Donor savedDonor = donorDao.save(donor);

    }
```

- Without `@Transactional` The update SQL is generated and the database
  is updated.
- With `@Transactional` The update SQL is not generated, does not appear
  in the log.  There are no exceptions, stepping over the Save method
  in my Dao implementation everything appears fine.  The bean passed in
  has the correct values (updated field values), the bean returned has
  the updated field values - just no SQL generated.

  ```
  @Override
  public Donor save(Donor bean) {

      getSession().saveOrUpdate(bean);
      return bean;
  }
  ```

The reason I need `@Transactional` is to allow the address to the LAZY.
Without `@Transactional` I can't access the address as LAZY due to exception "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: could not initialize proxy - no Session"

Comment: Which is actually as expected... The transaction is committed AFTER the transaction ends, which is after your test method. But as the test isn't committing but rolling back (the default behavior) no update will be issued.

Comment: Ahh of course.. So by removing @ Transactional the transaction commits with the saveOrUpdate call, whereas when the method is marked as @ Transactional the transaction abort is called as the method completes

Thank you !! Can you add that as an answer rather than a comment so I can accept.  Is there a way to prevent rollback on Spring tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which is as expected.

A transaction is started as soon as a `@Transactional` method is detected and committed as soon as that method call ends. Which in the case of a test is after the end of the test method. So during your tests you will not see the SQL.

Also when using `@Transactional` on a Spring based test it will by default do a rollback instead of a commit. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testing-tx) in the reference guide on the default and how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was provided by [M Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) as a comment